# NavigationBar missing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to make a login view controller, but at the beginning, I have a navigation bar on my Home view controller but when I disconnect and connect after I lose navigation bar.

I put some image.

[image: HomeViewController]

I press the cross button on left side of the navigation bar

```
@objc func handleDisconnect() -> Void {
    let vc = LoginViewController()
    self.present(vc, animated: true) {

    }
}
```

[image: LoginViewController]

I press connect button

```
 @objc func handleConnect() -> Void {
    print("handleConnect")
    let vc = ViewController()
    present(vc, animated: true) {
    }
}
```

[image: HomeViewController]

I'm back on HomeViewController and I lost navigation bar

How can I keep navigation bar when I'm logging?

Thanks guys

Comment: present viewcontroller does not embed with Navigation controller

Comment: You need to present the controller inside a navigation controller. try something like this `present(UINavigationController(rootController: vc), animated: true)`

Comment: Thanks dude it's workin :D

Comment: Glad that it helped ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1.** Push the new view controller onto your existing navigation stack, rather than presenting:

```
let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourVCIdentifier") as! yourVCName
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
```

**Option 2.** Embed your new view controller into a new navigation controller and present the new navigation controller modally:

```
let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourVCIdentifier") as! yourVCName
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.
self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: its the alternate solution , what about present VC with UINavigationController

Comment: I have used only this one

Comment: Thanks for the alternative way

Comment: I'm using push instead of show, keep in mind that's depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use at the view controller you want to show navigation bar:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to present the controller inside a navigation controller. try something like this:

```
present(UINavigationController(rootController: vc), animated: true)
```

Comment: add dismiss Call also

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, solution is very easy, when you create segue from your login screen to main, make segue to **Tab bar controller** not to View Controller